External Service Failures in Long-Running Queued Tasks
I'm developing an application where we process long-running tasks using a queue system (e.g., Asynq in Go). These tasks often interact with external services (cloud storage providers) to upload files or perform other operations. Occasionally, these external services may become unavailable or fail due to network issues, service outages, or other transient problems.
I'm looking for best practices on how to handle failures when interacting with external services within these long-running queued tasks.
What's the best way to implement retries with increasing delays (exponential backoff) to handle transient failures?
Is Circuit Breaker Pattern required here?
Should I re-enqueue tasks with delays manually or do I need some sort of automatic mechanism?
What to do in case of multiple failures?
Edit: there can be concurrent upload requests at the same time (depends on the users but can go up to 100 at the moment)
Edit2: seems like I explained the issue badly, we are a cloud service provider and we allow our admins to define their object storages. the objects to save are recording files and can go up to 1Gigabyte.
We are in a multi-tenancy environment so there can be a lot of users with the same object storage. Example: we have 100 tenants and each tenant can have multiple object storages. each tenant has 100 users and each user can have multiple recordings that need to be uploaded to their tenant object storage.
We don't want to keep their recordings in our local storage for too long (takes too much space for a large amount of recordings) that's why I was thinking about retrying. So let's say there is one object storage that is down, should I let all recordings try once for that same object storage that is down and fail? (that's why I was thinking of Circuit breaker pattern) all these recordings are in the queue, and when one object storage is down, let's say I have put 30 seconds timeout on it, 100 recordings in that queue means 1000*30 seconds of doing nothing but failing.
I also was thinking of keeping the status of that object storage, but updating that status for many object storages is a problem that I could not find any solutions for and I don't know which approach is better here. We do want to have alerting systems to tell tenant admins that their service is down and maybe manual retries. We live in a country with a lot of network problems and restrictions on services, that's why I think having a retry is necessary.

The easiest and common solution is to reenqueue such tasks after a delay. With a counter indicating number of retries. When reached some threshold log it and discard the task, or maybe store it somewhere else. This likely requires manual intervention anyway.

The "best way" is starting with a proper requirements analysis. What are the business consequenes of a failing tasks, and how quick do they need resolvement? How often do network issues, service outages or other problems typically last? How do these tasks depend on each other? How likely is that a simple retry mechanism can automatically resolve a problem - or can it lead to more problems than it solves? Finding out these things is your job, and after you have done this, I think you will already have answered most of your question by yourself.

@DocBrown Thanks, I updated the question and added more details about our scenario.

Retries are inherently dangerous. Unless you know what failure you are expecting and that a retry will fix the problem, then I would avoid any immediate retries.
The default approach should be to put the task in the error queue and send an alert. Then a human can diagnose and resend as required.
Circuit Breakers should only be used if you have an alternative way of completing a task when the failed operation can't be used. For example; say during a christmas sale you know you cant processes credit cards fast enough, but are happy that 99% will clear overnight, you might allow a purchase without completing the transaction.
Back off retries can be used where you have a known intermittent issue that a retry will fix, but know that an immediate retry will likey fail due to the same issue still being in effect. For example; a poor wifi connection which keeps dropping and reconnecting.
Adding retries or breakers universally to all operations can lead to cascading failures and more errors than if you had just let a transaction fail. for example a transaction delayed by a silent retry in a dependency might itself timeout, and then in turn be retried.
The best approach is to find the cause of the failure and fix it.
Given your case where it sounds like the tennant owned storage is just inherently unreliable, presumably some tenants are less tech savvy than others and their end might just be turned off.
I would suggest the following

have a queue per tenant
process messages one at a time
use a resumable file transfer protocol

In the event of a failure

Attempt to resume every x min
Send a message to the tenant after y failures. "please fix your thing"
Give them some admin interface so they can see the queue of pending files and the error messages with a resend button

Because you only process the files one at a time you aren't using all your bandwidth with retries and you optimise your use of the bandwidth available to the tenant server.
The resume protocol saves you from looping in a retry forever on big files where the upload time might be greater than the mean time to failure
The admin panel gently pushes the problem onto the tenant a bit. Hopefully they will be incentivised to fix any issues their end and you can also add warnings and opinions if they start to abuse your local storage

hello, thanks for this answer, I updated the question to clarify my usecase better. I would appreciate if you could take a look at it again

Hi, I read your edit 2. It seems like if a tenant storage is known to be down you should stop all uploads and notify the tenant. You can gove them an admin tool with a button to restart the uploads maybe or have a second task which checks to see if its back up every 5 min or so and then restarts

re: parallel uploads and unreliable connections. Given that you seem to have a single local to tenant site wouldn't you be better off with transfering one file at a time and using a resumable ftp protocol?

wdym by single local? - I understand the new approach you suggested, looks fine, but having 100 tenants and 100 queues doesn't seem ok somehow. Other than that, the task queue projects (like asynq or machinery) do not really have that feature to add queues while server is up and running. unless we implement the whole task queue ourselves, I'm not sure it's worth it and definitely will create a lot of bugs to implement all those features that a task queue manager has.

and let's get to the worst scenario, we have 500 tenants, so 500 queues, how many threads should I run? like 20-30 maybe? and what if all of them fail and are waiting to retrieve 1 minute timeout, doesn't that mean all those 30 threads are just doing nothing and other queues can't get their tasks done ?! So some how I need to keep track of external object storages statuses, doesn't that mean I still need that circuit breaker? like how should I manage all those queues? which one to run? which one to hold?

I would have a thread per queue and scale out to multiple machines running queue processor apps

im not familiar with asynq but adding multiple queues like this is a standard pattern with queues. Since you know all the tenants you know all the queues

Do you know any technologies or services that we could use?

I would look at rabbitmq, kafka or any AMQP implementation
